# A proof on continuous functions

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove this statement, provided it is true:

"A function is continuous at $x_0$ iff for every open $O$ containing $f(x_0)$, there exists an open $U$ containing $x_0$, such that for every $x\in U$, $f(x)\in O$."

(Def: A function $f:X\to Y$ is continuous at $x_0$ iff for all $O$ containing $f(x_0)$ its pre-image $f^{-1}(O)$ is an open set containing $x_0$.)

I can prove the forward case: if $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ then its pre-image $f^{-1}(O)$ is the open set in question, which for every $x\in f^{-1}(O)$, $f(x)\in O$.

But I'm having difficulty proving the converse. Firstly, how do I prove that $f^{-1}(O)$ is open?

I only know the tools from the definition of a topology. So I considered the union $\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}U_\alpha$, where $U_\alpha$ contains $x_0$ and for every $x\in U_\alpha$, $f(x)\in O$. If I can show that this union is $f^{-1}(O)$, then I proved that $f^{-1}(O)$ is both open and contains $x_0$. Obviously by construction, $\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}U_\alpha\subseteq f^{-1}(O)$. Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true!.

Let $f(x)=x$ if $x$ is rational and $x^{2}$ if $x$ is irrational. Take $x_0=0$. Then it is easy to see that for every open set $O$ containing $0$ there is an open set $U$ containing $0$ such that $f(U) \subset O$. However $f^{-1} (-2,2)$ is not an open set. For this look at the points in $(\sqrt 2, 2)$ which belong to $f^{-1} (-2,2)$ .

Comment: Thank you. Apparently, the definition I referenced was not correct. I'll have to review the definition of a continuous function at $x_0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy does the statement "a function is continuous at $x_0$ iff for every open $O$ containing $f(x_0)$, there exists an open $U$ containing $x_0$, such that for every $x\in U$, $f(x)\in O$" have a problem because it says $f$ is only continuous at a single point, $x_0$? If $f$ was continuous everywhere, would it be true?